# Using a function as dictionary key

Tags: python

Is it considered bad form to use a function as a dictionary key? For example:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

mydict = {add: "hello"}
```

Comment: what you trying to figure out here???

Comment: `add` is not the name of a function, it *is* a function.  The *name* is the string `'add'`, also accessible as `add.__qualname__`.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're hoping to solve with this? (It really is not obvious what you might want to do with `mydict`.)

Comment: My question is purely academic. Just wanted to know whether it's considered bad form. Is it a quirk of Python that this is allowed?

Comment: thanks @5gon12eder, I amended the question

Comment: depending on your _actual_ needs it may be perfectly valid or rather weird.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly valid. You could for instance use it to store a counter to how many times a function was called:

```
def hi():
    print('hi')

funcs = {hi: 0}

print(funcs)
# {<function hi at 0x10fb39950>: 0}

for func in funcs:
    func()
    # hi
    funcs[func] += 1

print(funcs)
# {<function hi at 0x10fb39950>: 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

Functions are represented through instance of `function` class:

```
>>> def f():
...   pass
...
>>> f
<function f at 0x000001D397363E18>
>>> help(type(f))

class function(object)
 |  function(code, globals[, name[, argdefs[, closure]]])
```

So the function class is derived from `object` class and inherits `__hash__` method. The default implementation of `__hash__` method in `object` class computes hash using return value of `id()` by [rotating right 4 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38519187/207661). The `id()` of object is memory address.

So that's how functions get hash. Anything that has *some* immutable state can technically have hash.