# Functions as list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code. I wanted to try different feature selection algorithms without repeating the same code twice so, I put the function names in the list and wrote the following code to see if it works. It did.

My question is, how can a list have function names as its items, and how is it actually working in the for loop?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)

list=[mutual_info_classif,chi2]

for i in list:
    print(type(i))
    X_new = SelectKBest(i, k=20).fit_transform(X, y)
    print(X_new)
    print('hello')
```

*Output**

```
<class 'function'>
[[ 5. 13. 15. ...  6.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  9. ...  0. 10.  0.]
 [ 0.  3. 14. ...  0. 16.  9.]
 ...
 [ 1. 13.  2. ...  2.  6.  0.]
 [ 2. 14. 15. ...  5. 12.  0.]
 [10. 16.  1. ...  8. 12.  1.]]
hello
<class 'function'>
[[ 1.  0. 15. ...  6.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.  9. ...  0. 10.  0.]
 [12.  0. 14. ...  0. 16.  9.]
 ...
 [ 1.  0.  2. ...  2.  6.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 15. ...  5. 12.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1. ...  8. 12.  1.]]
hello
```

Comment: @bunbun this code works...I have put the output also from the code

Comment: oops yes misread your question

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to remove everything `sklearn`-related from the question, because many people aren't familiar with that. And the question isn't related to `sklearn` at all anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are not putting the "name" of the function into the list as such. Functions are objects just like everything else in Python. When you create a function object with a `def` statement, you bind it to a name, as if with `=`, and also set the object's `__name__` attribute. When you place those names in a list, the list contains references to function objects that you can call later.

The `for` loop binds the references to the name `i` one by one. You may want to print `i.__name__` in addition to `type(i)` to see which function is being passed to `SelectKBest` with each iteration.

It is fairly common to see functions being processed this way in Python. Functions, and other callable objects, can be placed into lists, dictionaries, tuples, and just about any other data structure. Since [functions are hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38518849/2988730), they can even be used as dictionary keys or placed in a set. You can also add attributes to a function object just by assigning them.

Comment: then shouldnt the item type in the list be a pointer or memory address ?its returning function type

Comment: @ubuntu_noob. Under the hood it's a pointer to an object. `type` also happens to accept a pointer. At that level everything is a pointer. For example, `3`is a pointer to an `int` object in Python.

Comment: and is this a correct way to iterate through multiple functions?..is there any chance of memory problems?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob. Not much chance of error, barring a major but in your Python interpreter or some catastrophic failure. Functions are very much meant to be passed around like that in Python. That's one of the things that come from them being first class objects. There are lots of tools to help you do it.